# What determines data constructor order in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

When I run this on Haskell:

```
[2] <= [1,5]
```

I get False.

However, when I run this:

```
data T = A | B | C T T deriving (Eq,Ord)
A <= B && B <= C A A
```

I get True.

Why is this? Shouldn't B <= C A A be false for the same reason [2] < [1,5] is too?

Comment: No, Haskell will, for a "automatically generated" `Ord`, first compare the constructors (in the order these are defined). Only  if the data constructor is the same, it will lexicographically compare the parameters.

Comment: "Shouldn't B <= C A A be false for the same reason [2] < [1,5] is too?" No, but `C B B <= C A A` is false for that reason.

Comment: You can see the instances generated by `deriving` with the `-ddump-deriv` flag, and make the output a little more readable with options like `-dsuppress-uniques` and `-dsuppress-module-prefixes`. These options can be added on the command line, in the `ghc-options` field in a Cabal file, or with the pragma `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -ddump-deriv -dsuppress-uniques -dsuppress-module-prefixes #-}` in a module.

Answer (score 7):

The [Haskell report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/derived.html) specifies how the automatically derived instances should look like:

> **10.1  Derived instances of `Eq` and `Ord`**
>
> The class methods automatically introduced by derived instances of
>   `Eq` and `Ord` are `(==)`, `(/=)`, `compare`, `(<)`, `(<=)`, `(>)`,
>   `(>=)`, `max`, and `min`. **The latter seven operators are defined so
>   as to compare their arguments lexicographically with respect to the
>   constructor set given, with earlier constructors in the datatype
>   declaration counting as smaller than later ones**.
>
> For example, for the `Bool` datatype, we have that `(True > False) ==
>   True`.
>
> Derived comparisons **always traverse constructors from left to
>   right**. These examples illustrate this property:
>
> ```
>   (1,undefined) == (2,undefined) =>    False
>   (undefined,1) == (undefined,2) =>    _|_
> ```
>
> All derived operations of class `Eq` and `Ord` are strict in both
>   arguments. For example, `False <= _|_ is _|_`, even though `False` is
>   the first constructor of the `Bool` type.

So Haskell will implement an `Ord` function here where, regardless of the arguments, an object with data constructor `A` will be less than an object with data constructor `B`, and an object with data constructor `B` is less than an object with data constructor `C`. This is because `A` has been defined before `B` has been defined.

Only in case the data constructor is the same, it compares the arguments lexicographically: so first the first arguments of both objects are compares, and if these are not equal, that is the result of the comparison, in case these are, then we compare the second arguments, and so on.

So for your `T` type, these are implemented as:

```
instance Ord T where
    (<=) A A = True
    (<=) A B = True
    (<=) A (C _ _) = True
    (<=) B C = True
    (<=) B (C _ _) = True
    (<=) (C xa ya) (C xb yb) = xa <= xb || (xa == xb && ya <= yb)
    (<=) _ _ = False
```

If a list is defined as:

```
data [] a = [] | (:) a ([] a)
```

then the order of a list also follows from that definition, since an empty list is less than a non-empty list, and in case we compare two non-empty lists, we first compare the first elements (first argument of the "cons" data constructor), and then in case of an equal head, we compare the tails (second argument of the "cons" constructor). So an automatic derivation would look like:

```
import Data.Monoid((<>))

instance Ord ([] a) where
    compare [] [] = EQ
    compare [] (_:_) = LT
    compare (_:_) [] = GT
    compare (ha:ta) (hb:tb) = compare ha hb <> compare ta tb
```

here the `(<>)` operator for `Ordering`s takes the left element if it is not equal to `EQ` and the right element otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

An auto-generated `Ord` instance will consider one value less than another if it's constructor comes before the other in the list of constructors. If the constructors are the same, it will compare the elements pair-wise in lexicographical order. The `Ord` instance for lists acts the same way if we assume that `[]` comes before `:`.

The reason that `[2] <= [1,5]` is false is that `[2]` (a.k.a. `2 : []`) and `[1,5]` (a.k.a. `1:5:[]`) both use the same constructor, so it will compare `2` and `1` and `2` is greater than `1`.

This reason does not apply to `B <= C A A` at all. `B` and `C A A` do not use the same constructor, so `B` wins because it comes before `C` in the list of constructors.